# Remember zip code after we visit other Product page

Tags: magento-1, product-view, cash-on-delivery, zipcode

we are using custom module for checking COD is available or not in view page.

we entered zip code and checked "COD is available or not", now if we click

on other product page, it should remember the zip code that we entered last time & should display message by default.

[image]

**checkdelivery.phtml**

```
<div class="block block-list block-check-delivery">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php $blockLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/block_title'); ?>
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($blockLabel) ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" >        
        <br>
            <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
            <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
            <div id="delivery-message"></div>
            <?php $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html'); ?>
            <div id="delivery-html"><?php echo $defaultHtml ?></div>

        <br>        
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            method: "get",
            parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                 $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
                 $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                 $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**view.phtml**

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

**indexcontroller.php**

```
<?php
class NextBits_CheckDelivery_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {

        $zip = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode');
        $pincodearray = array();
        $pindata = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode');
        $pincodearray = explode(",", $pindata);
        $success = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_messgae');
        $failure = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_messgae');
        $empty = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/empty_messgae');
        $successHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_html');
        $failureHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_html');
        $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html');

        $trimedZip = trim($zip);
        $response = array();
        if(isset($trimedZip) && !empty($trimedZip)){
            if (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray)) {
                $response['message'] = $success;
                $response['color'] = 'green';
                $response['html'] = $successHtml;

            }else{
                $response['message'] = $failure;
                $response['color'] = 'red';
                $response['html'] = $failureHtml;

            }
        }else{
            $response['message'] = $empty;
            $response['color'] = 'orange';
            $response['html'] = $defaultHtml;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `checkdelivery/index` controller

Comment: are you asking for indexcontroller.php file ?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: we are using this [module](http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html)

Comment: updated code in question, please check it.

Comment: OK! I m checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `checkdelivery.phtml` with below code

```
<style>
.block-check-delivery .block-title strong {background-image:none; font-size: 11px;}
.block-check-delivery .block-content {padding:0 10px;  }
.block-check-delivery .button {float: right;}
.block-check-delivery input{width: 107px;}
</style>
<div class="block block-list block-check-delivery">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php $blockLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/block_title'); ?>
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($blockLabel) ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" >        
        <br>
            <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('zip'); ?>" maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
            <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
            <div id="delivery-message"></div>
            <?php $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html'); ?>
            <div id="delivery-html"><?php if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message')){
    echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message');
}
else{
    $defaultHtml; } ?></div>

        <br>        
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            method: "get",
            parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                 $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
                 $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                 $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the `indexController.php`

```
<?php
class NextBits_CheckDelivery_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {

        $zip = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode');
        $pincodearray = array();
        $pindata = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode');
        $pincodearray = explode(",", $pindata);
        $success = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_messgae');
        $failure = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_messgae');
        $empty = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/empty_messgae');
        $successHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_html');
        $failureHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_html');
        $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html');

        $trimedZip = trim($zip);
        $response = array();
        if(isset($trimedZip) && !empty($trimedZip)){
            if (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray)) {
                $response['message'] = $success;
                $response['color'] = 'green';
                $response['html'] = $successHtml;

            }else{
                $response['message'] = $failure;
                $response['color'] = 'red';
                $response['html'] = $failureHtml;

            }
        }else{
            $response['message'] = $empty;
            $response['color'] = 'orange';
            $response['html'] = $defaultHtml;
        }

        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('message', $response['message']);
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('zip', $zip);
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('html', $response['html']);
        echo json_encode($response);exit;
    }
}
```

Here i saved the customer entered data on cookie using

```
 Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('message', $response['message']);
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('color', $response['color']);
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('html', $response['html']);
```

And simple retrieve the value using `Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('message')`.

**Hope this will help you.. Happy learning**

Comment: but it didt worked for me.

Comment: Did you replace your code with my code???

Comment: ya, i did that.....

Comment: Show me your `indexController.php` and `checkdelivery.phtml` code

Comment: sorry, message is saving that "COD is available or not" but "zip code" is not saving

Comment: pls check here : http://prnt.sc/awl4ti

Comment: I update my answer! do the same things again for both files..

Comment: it working for next one product. means if we click next  one product page , 
its working . but for second product page, its not working.

Comment: Try to remove **5** from `Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('message', $response['message'], 5);
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('zip', $zip, 5);
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('html', $response['html'], 5);` on controller page

Comment: Just Make it Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('message', $response['message']);

Comment: please check and correct me : http://pasted.co/2df528d6

Comment: NO you are wrong. I told you to change indexcontroller.php but you changed the `phtml` page.. Just update my answer chack again and do same thing

Comment: It is my pleasure that i can help you

Answer (score 2):

You can save your zip code for user's session in your controller    `checkdelivery/index/index`. It will look like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('custom_zip_code', $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode'));
```

And get it everywhere during a single user’s session:

```
$zip = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData('custom_zip_code');
```

Comment: i tried your code in checkdelivery.phtml code as [here](http://pasted.co/560fcfae) but it didt worked, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This code `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('custom_zip_code', $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode')); ` should be used in the controller.

Comment: This will not work if customer is not logged in!

Comment: @MageWorx same code is there in answer also right? i tried with same, please check it. i added your code in checkdelivery.phtml file

Answer (score 1):

to store zip code you can use registry like  Mage::register('zip-code', $your-data); and on product page you have to use $zip-code= Mage::registry('zip-code'); and then if($zip-code > 0) { echo 'Cash on delivery is available';} and put the value in textbox.